# How can I get Google Sheets to automatically check for 10 rep sets then of all those instances look at the weight and find the highest weight?

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to have a command to check all the entries for set numbers then if there is a set with 10 or more reps have it look to the weight number and then of all the weights it finds put the greatest weight in the cell to the right of 10 rep max.

Image showing the area I would like it too look for 10 sets or more:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

A single-cell formula that uses [BYROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930) to process each row in a range, and [MAX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094013) to return the largest value

```
=MAX(BYROW(B3:J6, LAMBDA(r, 
    IF(MAX(r)>=10, OFFSET(INDEX(r,,1),0,-1),))))
```

[image]

#### Explanation

1. [BYROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930) passes each row from the range `B3:J6` (in my example) one by one into a [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) function that assigns the variable `r` to represent each row in its formula.
   [image]
2. For each mapped row `r`, [MAX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094013) returns the highest number of "Reps": `MAX(r)`
   [image]
3. [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364) tests whether the [MAX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094013) value for `r` is equal to or greater than 10 and, where TRUE, [OFFSET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379) is used to return the "Total Weight" value for that row: `IF(MAX(r)>=10,OFFSET(INDEX(r,,1),0,-1),)`
   [image]
4. [MAX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094013) is used to return the heaviest weight from all weights (if any) that were returned by the [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364) condition.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting an additional cell on each line that gives the max reps per set by using the `MAX` function. The function for this would be `=MAX([range of all sets for that row])`. Then you can use `=MAXIFS([range for weights], [range for max reps per set for that weight], ">=10")` to get the highest weight that you did more than 10 reps in a set for.